# How to Read and Show ADC value of STM32F4 using HAL Library

Tags: c, adc, stm32f4

I have a code generated by STMCubeMX where I use the portal PA0 like ADC Input. I'm trying to read this input using HAL Library of STM in C and transmit the value to USB port using CDC. See the main, where i try to get the data and show this:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t buffer[8];

    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();

    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

    while (1)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_14);
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
        sprintf((char*)buffer,"%d\n",(int)HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1));
        //HAL_Delay(500);
        CDC_Transmit_FS(buffer,8);
    }
}
```

Debugging the code I saw that function "HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000)" never returns "HAL_OK".
In the terminal, a single value appears.

UPDATE

Well, for the code works I have to put the "Start" of ADC inside of infinit loop and a call of "Stop" on the final of loop.
Ps: The Adc is running on continuous conversion mode.

```
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t buffer[8];

    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();

    while (1)
    {
        HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_14);
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
        sprintf((char*)buffer,"%d\n",(int)HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1));
        //HAL_Delay(500);
        CDC_Transmit_FS(buffer,8);
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
}
```

}

Comment: Does the ADC run in continuous conversion mode (or however it might be called)?  Else it runs in single conversion mode and you need to start it every time before polling for the end of the conversion.

Comment: yes, I did this in the CubeMX, but even so I need to put the start of ADC inside the infinit loop and a Stop command to make it work.

Comment: OK, if you have a solution now, please write an answer and mark it to help others looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to the answer in the comments:

The call to `HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);` explicitly stops the conversion, even if continuous conversion is activated.

If you you want/must wait for each conversion to get finished, you must restart the ADC with `HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);` after waiting (and reading) for the result.